# Node conflict: Nodejs -v works, but not node -v

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, raspberry-pi

So, I'm trying to install node.js on my raspberry pi 3 which is running on Raspbian OS. When I first picked it up, I installed node.js 8.9.0 following some tutorials, but for some reason I already had node installed before and when I would run `nodejs -v` I would get 8.9.0 version back but if I run `node -v` I would get version 4.3.2. So there was some version conflict. I tried to uninstall both, but after uninstalling both and typing `node -v` I would still get version 4.3.2. So by following some tuts, I also deleted `node_modules` from `/usr/local/lib` and all the other dir's. Then I installed nodejs again and finally when I run nodejs -v I get 8.9.0 version, but `node -v` command doesn't work at all. I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/node: No such file or directory` error to the Terminal.

So what's the problem and how can I fix it? How can it be that nodeJS is working but not node? I created a simple server file and tried to run it using node command and it doesn't work because of this. Bear in mind that I'm totally linux newbie so command line and file structure is foreign to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a symlink between the two using.

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

Comment: Yes, just after creating this question, I tried symlink and it worked just fine. Thanks.